# Переход по параметру URL без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

У меня есть страница **www.xxx.ru** в которой есть категории.
При клике по категории URL становится такого вида **www.xxx.ru/?SECTION_ID=4**  и заменяются эти категории на магазины. Но проблема в том что страница перезагружается и перекидывает меня в начало страницы

Comment: Где вы хотите его открыть?

Comment: На этой же странице

Answer (score 2):

1. При смене урла любым способом страница перезагрузится. Собственно, это сама основа гипертекста.
2. Используйте вместо параметра в урле имя якоря. То есть, не `my_address.com/page?section_id=4`, а `my_address.com/page#section_4`, расставив секциям соответствующие якоря (`<a name = "section_4"></a>`).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) Например, 
`history.pushState({}, 'Your title', '?SECTION_ID=4')`